# Blazor Webassembly with Google Oauth Email confirmation fails with InvalidOperationException: No page named '/Index'

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I created a new project from .NET 7 templates: Blazor Webassembly app with Individual Accounts - ASP.NET Core hosted and added Microsoft.AspnetCore.Authentication.Google and a Google authentication connection with this:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
{
    googleOptions.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"] ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'Authentication:Google:ClientId' not found.");
    googleOptions.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"] ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'Authentication:Google:ClientSecret' not found.");
});
```

Authentication via Google works properly without Email confirmation; just the final self-confirmation click.

After adding Email confirmation via a new EmailSender service :

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
```

The Email send works and creates a link starting with https://localhost:7040/Identity/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId=21c0f.....  When the link is clicked, it produces the error

```
InvalidOperationException: No page named '/Index' matches the supplied values.
```

Trying to navigate directly to the address https://localhost:7040/Identity/Account/ConfirmEmail produces the same error message.  A trace shows that the page should have been initialized:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.DefaultViewCompiler: Debug: Initializing Razor view compiler with compiled view: '/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/ConfirmEmail.cshtml'.
```

What else needs to be configured or how can this be debugged?

Answer (score 0):

This can diagnosed by scaffolding the identity functions into the Server project.  In this case, the confirmation Email contained an invalid escape sequence in the query string arguments:

```
&amp;code=
```

I performed this hack in In   {project}\Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\ConfirmEmail.cshtml.cs :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string userId, string code)
        {
//>>>> BEGIN ADD
            var queryParameters = HttpContext.Request.Query;

            if (code == null)
            {
                if (queryParameters.ContainsKey("amp;code")) code = queryParameters["amp;code"]; // Handle double-encoding
            }
//<<< END ADD
            if (userId == null || code == null)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("/Index");
            }
```